# Rookie Cut - Which movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie

A friend of mine recently cut his brow on the scope of a rifle, and now has a crescent moon scar just above his eyebrow.

I distinctly remember seeing such a thing in a movie (5-10 years ago, but movie itself may be older) where I recall such a scar being referred to as a 'Rookie Cut'; although as a Google search for the term brings no results I may be wrong about that.

From what I recall from the scene, someone is posing as a seasoned vet or experienced soldier; but it is observed by another character that they are an amateur due to fresh cut on their forehead, which comes from putting ones eye too close behind a rifle scope.

Can anyone identify what film I'm remembering, ideally before I lose my mind completely?

Comment: I don't know the film, but the actual term is called "scope bite"

Comment: A bit of a long shot, but could it be Ronin (1998)

Comment: When does this happen in Ronin? I'm trying to find the clip..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sabotage (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117533/?ref_=ttkw_kw_tt)

You can watch the complete movie here, with Russian dubbing, unfortunately:

There are two rookie cuts in this movie. At the 0:29:30 mark starts the scene where an inexperienced first-time killer uses a sniper rifle during an assassination attempt. A few minutes later, after a chase in the woods, he is shot dead by the bodyguard (played by Mark Dacascos). Dacascos and the female police detective (played by Carrie-Anne Moss) investigate the body and **at the 0:32:55 mark Dacascos points out the rookie cut mark around the eye of the dead killer (first picture below)**. Some minutes later, Carrie-Anne Moss fires the sniper rifle (second picture below). Being a police detective, she has not much experience with sniper/hunter rifles and she obtains the cut. Dacascos, ex-special forces, familiar with these types of weapons and their handling, points to her cut, and **the crescent-shaped rookie cut is clearly visible above her eyebrow at the 0:34:14 mark** when she tries to clean it with a handkerchief (third picture below).

[image: Rokkie cut on dead killer]

[image: Carrie-Ann fires the sniper rifle]

[image: Rookie cut next to her right eyebrow]

Comment: Incredible! I can't believe someone actually found this!

Comment: I saw the movie in the 90's, liked it very much, and the scene immediately came to mind. Your description was good.